# Bulk Ordering a Product with Many Possible Configurations

Tags: attributes, orders, filter

I am building a website that sells different types of fasteners (nuts, bolts, screws, etc).

The issue is that each product has many, many different variations.  For instance, a hex head cap screw has the following variations:

- Grade:  3 types
- Thread:  2 types
- Plating:  3 types
- Diameter:  12 types
- Length:  29 types

Furthermore, we sell it in different quantities.

- 100 / box
- 500 / box
- 1000 / box, etc.

What I would like is a single page where I can filter the results so that ONLY those configurations that a customer wants appear.  For instance, only Grade 5 and 8, coarse thread, zinc plated and non-plated with 3 different diameters and 4 different lengths

Then, I want a customer to be able to go down that list and add the different amounts that they want to the cart.

So, 2 boxes at 100 per box for one configuration; 3 boxes at 500 per box for another, etc.

Is this possible with Magento?  If so, how so?

I thank you in advance for any help you can offer.